# Which term I can use to point "successor" or "predecessor"?

Tags: terminology

I have some set which contains two elements "successor" and "predecessor". How can I name the set? Maybe "Sequent"?

Comment: I'd call it a "set".

Comment: In general, the name given to a set does not have to describe mathematical or logical properties among the elements of the set. So I am not even sure I understand the question so I cannot venture a sensible answer.

Comment: *off-by-oner*?...

Comment: You might say "adjacencies".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sequent** seems to connote *subsequent* more than *antecedent*. For something more generic, how about **Adjacent**?